# Slow execution of TensorFlow 2.0. Update only a part of tf.Variable

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to translate a code from TensorFlow 1x to TensorFlow 2x. The code is an implementation of Word2Vec. The code is running properly but the execution is twice as slow from when I run it on TensorFlow 1x. I suppose that the problem is how I use tape.gradient and apply_gradients. Here is the code:

Here, I initialize my Variables.

```
#tensor that holds the embeddings
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([number_of_objects, size_of_embeddings]))

#Softmax weight
sm_w_t = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([number_of_objects, size_of_embeddings]))

#Softmax bias
sm_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([number_of_objects]))
```

In this part I compute the loss.

```
def word2vec(examples, labels, embeddings, sm_w_t, sm_b):
    
    sampled_ids, _, _ = tf.nn.fixed_unigram_candidate_sampler(
            true_classes=labels,
            num_true=1,
            num_sampled=num_sampled,
            unique=False,
            range_max=number_of_objects,
            distortion=0.75,
            unigrams=counts)
    
    # Embeddings for examples: [batch_size, emb_dim]
    example_emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, examples)

    # Weights for labels: [batch_size, emb_dim]
    true_w = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(sm_w_t, labels)
    # Biases for labels: [batch_size, 1]
    true_b = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(sm_b, labels)

    # Weights for sampled ids: [num_sampled, emb_dim]
    sampled_w = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(sm_w_t, sampled_ids)
    # Biases for sampled ids: [num_sampled, 1]
    sampled_b = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(sm_b, sampled_ids)

    # True logits: [batch_size, 1]
    true_logits = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(example_emb, true_w), 1) + true_b

    # Sampled logits: [batch_size, num_sampled]
    # We replicate sampled noise labels for all examples in the batch
    # using the matmul.
    sampled_b_vec = tf.reshape(sampled_b, [num_sampled])
    sampled_logits = tf.matmul(example_emb,
                               sampled_w,
                               transpose_b=True) + sampled_b_vec
    
    true_xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=tf.ones_like(true_logits), logits=true_logits)
    sampled_xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=tf.zeros_like(sampled_logits), logits=sampled_logits)

    # NCE-loss is the sum of the true and noise (sampled words)
    # contributions, averaged over the batch.
    nce_loss_tensor = (tf.reduce_sum(true_xent) +
                       tf.reduce_sum(sampled_xent)) / batch_size
    
    return nce_loss_tensor
```

In this part, I run a loop, computing gradients and updating my Variables.

```
for step in range(num_steps):
      batch_inputs, batch_labels = generate_training_batch(batch_size)
      
      opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
          loss_val = word2vec(batch_inputs, batch_labels, embeddings, sm_w_t, sm_b)
      
      gradients = tape.gradient(loss_val, [embeddings, sm_w_t, sm_b])
      opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [embeddings, sm_w_t, sm_b]))
```

I need only to calculate the gradients for the part of the Variables referring to the embedding_lookups. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras``` like this [https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings) ?